# how to get table price total in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I created code for the get total. But It will not adding value. That all values will show as a one line. What is the wrong in this code.**

**ProductController.js**

```
$scope.getTotal = function(type) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.products, function(el) {
            total += el[type];
        });
        return total;
    };
```

**cart.html**

```
<table class="cartdata">
<tr>
<th class="a">Name</th>
<th class="a">Price</th>
<th class="a">Post Date</th>
<th class="a">Remove Item</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="produ in products track by $index" ng-init="setTotals(produ)">
<td class='b'>{{produ.post_title}}</td>
<td class="b">{{produ.ID | currency}}</td>
<td class="b">
<a ng-click="delete(post.id, $index)" class="btn btn-danger"></a>
</td>
</tr>

<td>Total{{getTotal('ID') | currency }}</td>

</table>
```

**Cart view**

```
-------------------------
|   Name   |    Price   |
|------------------------
|Product 1 |  $20.00    |
|Product 2 |  $35.00    |
|Product 3 |  $10.00    |
|-----------------------|

Total = $ 203,510.00
```

Comment: your code is working for me.. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9adzjtLs/

Comment: OMG. But my code not working. Then What I need to do ?

Comment: I think you must have given ID as a string .. convert it into integer and then add

Comment: Here is the working "problem" with string values ~ http://jsfiddle.net/9adzjtLs/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s845a44/)

```
$scope.getTotal = function(type) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.products, function(el) {
        total += parseFloat(el[type]);
    });
    return total;
 };
```

Comment: Given that the fields are currency, I'd go with `parseFloat()`.